# Running maximum of numpy array values

Tags: python, numpy

I need a fast way to keep a running maximum of a numpy array. For example, if my array was:

```
x = numpy.array([11,12,13,20,19,18,17,18,23,21])
```

I'd want:

```
numpy.array([11,12,13,20,20,20,20,20,23,23])
```

Obviously I could do this with a little loop:

```
def running_max(x):
    result = [x[0]]
    for val in x:
        if val > result[-1]:
            result.append(val)
        else:
            result.append(result[-1])
    return result
```

But my arrays have hundreds of thousands of entries and I need to call this many times. It seems like there's got to be a numpy trick to remove the loop, but I can't seem to find anything that will work. The alternative will be to write this as a C extension, but it seems like I'd be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: i would call that the cumulative max - running max suggests a window to me.  unfortunately googling for that doesn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: i don't have numpy installed, but max.accumulate might work.  check out "accumulate" in the docs.

Comment: @andrew max doesn't have an accumulate attribute in numpy. That would have been a good built-in solution though if it did.

Comment: @JoshAdel: `numpy.maximum.accumulate`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`numpy.maximum.accumulate` works for me.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.maximum.accumulate(numpy.array([11,12,13,20,19,18,17,18,23,21]))
array([11, 12, 13, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 23, 23])
```

Comment: wim got there just before I did.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, there is `scipy.maximum.accumulate`:

```
In [9]: x
Out[9]: [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]

In [10]: scipy.maximum.accumulate(x)
Out[10]: array([1, 3, 3, 5, 5])
```

Comment: There is no need to get it from the scipy namespace. It's a numpy ufunc. The duplication of the numpy symbols in scipy.* is a backwards-compatibility leftover from the days of Numeric.

Comment: Sorry about that. Personal bias, I guess.