# maximum previous in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running maximum of numpy array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251421/running-maximum-of-numpy-array-values)

I'm looking for a maximum function in numpy that do something like :

```
a  = array([0.2,0.3,0.25,0.5,0.2,0.8])
maxi(a)
---> [0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.5,0.8]
```

thanks