# How can I get the running (cumulative) maximum of values in a list?

Tags: python

I want to create a list comprehension that keeps the previous value unless the next value is higher.

Example:
list_input = [3, 4, 2, 8, 9, 3, 3, 4, 20, 1]

list_output = [3, 4, 4, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 20, 20]

Is there a way to do this in a single list comprehension expression?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243806/discussion-on-question-by-mrclean-list-comprehension-keep-highest-value-in-a-li).

Answer (score 5):

One way to really just do it in a list comprehension:

```
list_output = [m
               for m in list_input[:1]
               for x in list_input
               for m in [max(m, x)]]
```

Better way:

```
from itertools import accumulate

list_output = list(accumulate(list_input, max))
```

Requested explanation for the list comprehension: It does pretty much the same as this:

```
list_output = []
if list_input:
    m = list_input[0]
for x in list_input:
    m = max(m, x)
    list_output.append(m)
```

Comment: Can't use itertools I only have access to numpy, pandas and few other modules in the application.
The list comprehension solution works great, thx for sharing! However I don't fully grasp what is going on. Do you mind walking me through what happens?

Comment: @mrClean You have access to third-party modules but not access to a standard library module that comes with Python? Why? That's really odd. Are you sure? Also: quick googling found a [NumPy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7251598/12671057) and I wouldn't be surprised if Pandas had one, too.

Comment: @mrClean Added something to hopefully clarify it.

Comment: numpy solution also did it. Thx again.