# Cumulative maximum of any iterable with a list comprehension

Tags: python, max, list-comprehension, accumulate

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71832334/12671057) asked to compute cumulative maximum of a list in a list comprehension, e.g.:

```
input:  [3, 4, 2, 8, 9, 3, 3, 4, 20, 1]
output: [3, 4, 4, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 20, 20]
```

I [came up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71832461/12671057) with a decent list comprehension there as requested, but it uses that the input is given as a list:

```
[m
 for m in list_input[:1]
 for x in list_input
 for m in [max(m, x)]]
```

My question/challenge: What if the input is an *iterator* or any other iterable? Should still be just a list comprehension and take only linear time. And of course not using `accumulate(iterable, max)`. I found one and I like it, but would like to see other people's solutions as well :-)

Testing code, leaving `cumulative_maximum` to implement ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/BjsIwDETv/Yo5tlIOu5QDuxJfghAqxaiRkjhyHQRfX9pQqMQBEeVgZ57Hk3jTjkO9iTIMZ2EPqyTK7HpYH1kUTdsmn1yjVBQnOmPu7IUOvrlan3w5zTRHR9V/gfEIaZKA3Y2TwNle0bKPQh2F3nJAR0L7h5lSr@/jzxZbaIqOFj3LdI3U6ihOzuWS7oUZjLmqB8xJY5rgT6kzGcUGLZ/8dl5jZofv3BbL7zyL/P1dbbA2WBlsDP4M6nynlx@D3301U6@iXqqsD8Md)):

```
from itertools import accumulate

def cumulative_maximum(iterable):
    return [your list comprehension here]

def test(iterable):
    iterable = tuple(iterable)
    expect = list(accumulate(iterable, max))
    output = cumulative_maximum(iterable)
    print(output == expect, output)
    output = cumulative_maximum(iter(iterable))
    print(output == expect, output)

test([3, 4, 2, 8, 9, 3, 3, 4, 20, 1])
test([])
test([3])
test([3, 1])
```

Comment: if we can use `tee`, then I think your original list comp works with minimal adjustment

Comment: @enke Yes, that would be alright. I really just rule out `accumulate`, as that pretty much does the whole job and isn't interesting at all.

Comment: `reduce(lambda x, r: x.append(max(r, x[-1])) or x, lst[1:], lst[:1])` :) No list comprehension, though

Comment: @njzk2 More importantly, it misses the point of the question. Even a *list* iterator can't be sliced like that.

Comment: well, it's just a way of writing _first_ and _rest_, avoiding ifs and elses, until python supports pattern matching for iterators as well. This does the same and works for iterables, though: `reduce(lambda x, r: x.append(x[-1] if x and x[-1] > r else r) or x, lst, [])`

Comment: I was messing around and it seems `first, second = tee(iterable); return [m for m in [next(first, [])] for x in second for m in [m if m>x else x]]` is 30% faster than `list(accumulate(iterable, max))`. I thought `accumulate` was optimized for this job. How is it slower? Also the equivalent numpy method seems to perform better than `accumulate` even on lists too.

Comment: @enke `accumulate` probably *is* faster if your list comp uses `max(m, x)`, no?

Comment: @enke `tee` slows it down a bit, but not by much. See benchmarks in my answer.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't understand your closing. Did you not read the question?

Answer (score 2):

If we can use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions), this works:

```
return [m := x if idx == 0 else max(m, x) for idx, x in enumerate(iterable)]
```

`enumerate`, `if`, and `else` are strictly for initializing `m`.

This is a Python 3.8+ solution.

Comment: Nice. Leaks the `m` variable to outside of the list comprehension, but that outside is just the function and it returns right away, so no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine and benchmarks:

```
def cumulative_maximum(iterable):
    return [m
            for it in [iter(iterable)]
            for m in it
            for xs in [[m], it]
            for x in xs
            for m in [max(m, x)]]
```

First I make sure I have an itera**tor**, calling it `it`. Then I initialize my maximum variable `m` with the first element (if there isn't one, we just stop right there). Then the iterator `it` only has the remaining elements, so I "chain" `m` back in front of it by going through `xs = [m]` and afterwards going through `xs = it`. And for each I go through the `x`-values and update/output `m`.

Benchmark on `iterable = iter([random.random() for _ in range(1000)])`:

```
Python 3.10.4:
 35.9 us   35.9 us   35.9 us  Kelly2
 42.3 us   42.4 us   42.5 us  enke
 43.3 us   43.4 us   43.5 us  loop2
 55.8 us   55.8 us   56.5 us  loop
 63.6 us   63.6 us   63.7 us  Kraigolas2
 74.8 us   74.9 us   75.2 us  accumulate_lambda
106.1 us  106.4 us  106.5 us  accumulate_max
120.6 us  120.7 us  120.7 us  Kelly
161.8 us  162.4 us  162.4 us  Kraigolas

Python 3.9.2:
 39.5 us   39.6 us   39.6 us  Kelly2
 45.9 us   46.1 us   46.2 us  enke
 47.4 us   47.6 us   47.6 us  loop2
 55.5 us   55.6 us   55.6 us  loop
 65.6 us   65.7 us   65.7 us  Kraigolas2
 74.4 us   74.6 us   74.6 us  accumulate_lambda
 93.0 us   93.1 us   93.2 us  accumulate_max
108.7 us  108.9 us  109.0 us  Kelly
143.8 us  143.8 us  143.8 us  Kraigolas
```

Note:

- My above solution is my slower one, the fast `Kelly2` version replaced `max(m, x)` with the faster `x if m < x else m`.
- @enke's suggestion with `tee` is a little slower than mine because it iterates through a `tee` iterator whereas mine iterates directly on the (iterator of the) given iterable. Also, it has the downside of additionally buffering all but the first element in memory in another structure, because the first `tee` iterator stays at the start while the second runs through.
- The `accumulate` and `loop` solutions don't use list comprehensions, but I included them anyway out of curiosity / for reference.
- The *"idiom for assignment a temporary variable in comprehensions"* that I'm using got [optimized in Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations).

Full benchmark code:

```
def cumulative_maximum_Kelly(iterable):
    return [m
            for it in [iter(iterable)]
            for m in it
            for xs in [[m], it]
            for x in xs
            for m in [max(m, x)]]

def cumulative_maximum_Kelly2(iterable):
    return [m
            for it in [iter(iterable)]
            for m in it
            for xs in [[m], it]
            for x in xs
            for m in [x if m < x else m]]

def cumulative_maximum_Kraigolas(iterable):
    return [m := x if idx == 0 else max(m, x) for idx, x in enumerate(iterable)]

def cumulative_maximum_Kraigolas2(iterable):
    return [m := x if not idx else x if m < x else m for idx, x in enumerate(iterable)]

def cumulative_maximum_enke(iterable):
    return [m
            for first, second in [tee(iterable)]
            for m in [next(first, [])]
            for x in second
            for m in [m if m > x else x]]

def cumulative_maximum_accumulate_max(iterable):
    return list(accumulate(iterable, max))

def cumulative_maximum_accumulate_lambda(iterable):
    return list(accumulate(iterable, lambda m, x: x if m < x else m))

def cumulative_maximum_loop(iterable):
    result = []
    it = iter(iterable)
    for m in it:
        result.append(m)
        for x in it:
            if m < x:
                m = x
            result.append(m)
    return result

def cumulative_maximum_loop2(iterable):
    result = []
    append = result.append
    it = iter(iterable)
    for m in it:
        append(m)
        for x in it:
            if m < x:
                m = x
            append(m)
    return result

funcs = [
    cumulative_maximum_Kelly,
    cumulative_maximum_Kelly2,
    cumulative_maximum_enke,
    cumulative_maximum_Kraigolas,
    cumulative_maximum_Kraigolas2,
    cumulative_maximum_accumulate_max,
    cumulative_maximum_accumulate_lambda,
    cumulative_maximum_loop,
    cumulative_maximum_loop2,
]

from timeit import repeat
from random import random
from itertools import tee, accumulate
import sys

tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
for _ in range(10):
    lst = [random() for _ in range(1000)]
    expect = funcs[0](iter(lst))
    for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
        assert func(iter(lst)) == expect
        t = min(repeat(lambda: func(iter(lst)), number=100)) / 100
        ts.append(t)
    for func, ts in sorted(zip(funcs, tss), key=lambda func_ts: sorted(func_ts[1])):
        print(*('%5.1f us ' % (t * 1e6) for t in sorted(ts)[:3]),
              func.__name__.removeprefix('cumulative_maximum_'))
    print()
print(sys.version)
```